# django password change completion fails

Tags: django, authentication, change-password

I have almost implemented the password reset process, but when I validate the password change I don't end up on the reset complete template and get the template says:

> The password reset link was invalid...

However, the password change has been made and can log in with the new password. It looks the redirection is wrong but I can't figure out why.

Here is my urls.py:

```
path('reset/<uidb64>/<token>', auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(
    template_name='news/user/password_reset_confirm.html',
    success_url='../password-change/done'), name='password_reset_confirm'),
path('password-change/done', auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(template_name='news/user/password_reset_complete.html'), name='password_change_done'),
```

Here is my template:

```
{% block content %}

{% if validlink %}

<p>Please enter your new password twice so we can verify you typed it in correctly.</p>

<form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
<fieldset class="module aligned">
    <div class="form-row field-password1">
        {{ form.new_password1.errors }}
        <label for="id_new_password1">New password:</label>
        {{ form.new_password1 }}
    </div>
    <div class="form-row field-password2">
        {{ form.new_password2.errors }}
        <label for="id_new_password2">Confirm password:</label>
        {{ form.new_password2 }}
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Change my password">
</fieldset>
</form>

{% else %}

<p>The password reset link was invalid, possibly because it has already been used.  Please request a new password reset.</p>

{% endif %}

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a final slash on the `password_reset_confirm` path, which is causing your POST to go to the wrong place. It should be:

```
path('reset/<uidb64>/<token>/', ...
```

Note that your `success_url` is also probably wrong, I doubt that `..` will work the way you think it will.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot Daniel. I've managed to make it work but had to change my to this long url, is this normal? `path('reset/Mg/set-password/password-change/done', auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(template_name='news/user/password_reset_complete.html'), name='password_change_done')`

Comment: `success_url='../password-change/done'` is wrong, a url is not supposed to contain file os-like paths (the `..`). That's probably why your user gets redirected to this weird url.